# What was "bathroom" called in 1900's?

Tags: phrases, history, euphemisms

What would have been said around 1900 for a woman saying she needed to go to the bathroom in the state of Virginia?

Comment: Why Virigina? There would have been plenty of other places to go to the bathroom.

Comment: @Barrie: What worries me is that Virginia only contained one bathroom back then.

Comment: What does your research show, Clark?

Comment: _Water closet_ and _W.C._ were common euphemisms then, coming after _crapper_ became tainted. _Toilette_ was a fancy word for a wash-up; one made one's toilette. _Toilet, bathroom,_ and _bowl_ are later euphemisms, after _W.C._ was retired.

Comment: I don't even know what you guys are talking about. Clearly it is not the bathroom that is the antedecent of "in the state of Virginia", but rather the woman. And she should go see a doctor about it, rather than a bathroom.

Comment: My wife prefers going to the bathroom in West Virginia. Thank goodness it's just an hour's drive from Pittsburgh! In her country of origin (Egypt) a common expression for bathroom is cabinet, pronounced cab ee nay' (accent on nay); hence, "Fain ill cab ee nay? (Where's the bathroom?)

Comment: "Ya seen my boots anywhere?" comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Would a woman have said she needed to go powder her nose/face/cheeks?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I was just suggesting an answer...

Comment: Oh, sorry. I was confused because you ended your answer with a question mark.